# Find a <a> tag that starts with a space in grep

Tags: grep

I want to search an entire codebase for spaces after an < a> tags. They are visible as underlined spaces. Is this possible with regular expressions and grep?

My first guess is that I must use a HTML parser, find all < a>s and check their "before" texts.

I want to find examples like:

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' owner.id %}"> {{ owner.get_full_name }}
```

to remove the offending spaces

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' owner.id %}">{{ owner.get_full_name }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a.*?>
```

Note that there is a trailing space at the end of that expression.

Basically it's looking for the `<a` then anything up to the next `>` with a space following. The ? is to say 'non-greedy repeat', ie only as much as is required to get to the next `>`.